# Using radians and iterating over array of hex colour values

Tags: p5.js

I have a number of hex values stored in an array. I am using the array index to increase the angle in radian and display a series of ellipses in a circle display a series of ellipses. Difficult to explain but I have a [pen](https://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/3f2c600d6f2e21b01ce192dea864da12?editors=0010). The issue is that when I use a for loop I'm not sure how to use the index to colour the ellipses.

```
const colors = ['#b1ede8','#db9a78','#eed4ad','#a989b2']

function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)
}

function draw(){
background(255,100,100)
 translate(width/2,height/2)
  noStroke();
  prizes(colors,200)
}

function windowResized(){
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)
}

function prizes(data,radius){

for(i = 0 ; i < TWO_PI ; i+=TWO_PI/data.length)
{
  let x = radius * cos(i);
  let y = radius * sin(i);
```

i is now a floating value in radians and the fill code does not work.

```
  fill(colors[i])
  ellipse(x,y,20)
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const colors = ['#b1ede8','#db9a78','#eed4ad','#a989b2']

function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)
}

function draw(){
background(255,100,100)
 translate(width/2,height/2)
  noStroke();
  prizes(colors,200)
}

function windowResized(){
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)
}

function prizes(data,radius){
 
var j = 0;
  
for(i = 0 ; i < TWO_PI ; i+=TWO_PI/data.length)
{
  let x = radius * cos(i);
  let y = radius * sin(i);
   
  fill(data[j])
  ellipse(x,y,20)
  j++;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.js"></script>
```

I think i found the problem. You used `i` to get the color value. But You don't increment `i` by 1. So you will get invalide numbers. I made a new variable `j` to index the color. Is this the result You are looking for?

Comment: You will have to view the result on full page (corner right) or you will only see 2 of the dots

Comment: Perfect. Spent so long trying to figure this out before coming to Stack Overflow. Many thaks

Comment: Yes I pasted it back in to my pen